# Cucumber: IDEA: No features found at "path" error

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I've got a problem.
When i'm trying to run my runner with tests, i've got error that "No features found". I'm trying to use "feature" parameter and without it. But still always got that error. Please someone helpt me. See screenshots [with "features"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98i3n.png) [without "features"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV7Se.png)

Comment: Try giving the full path to a single feature file -- src/test/...../cucum../steps/Add.feature. Not sure but removing the space in the feature file name might help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. You need to give your feature files extension ".feature". And better rename your "Runner" to "RunnerTest". It's helped me. Good luck everyone!